# Office Interop change for Microsoft word throws Exception for people who haven't updated yet

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I have an "Export to Word" procedure that won't work for those who have Word 2007(I have 2013). Is there a way to accommodate the different versions through reference or a setting i could change in my object?

Comment: yes you could use the OpenXml `using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;`

Comment: What line of code throws an exception? Did you try to debug the code?

Comment: I know what the problem is. The problem with this exception is that the station I run the workspace on has the correct DLL for 2013(I don't get the exception, only people who haven't gotten 2013) so there is no real way of debugging it.